# Reset a value in a model for all users each year - Django.

Tags: python, django

I am developing a Django application that tracks an employees holiday. I am not to sure how I would go about resetting the holiday each year at a specific date. Are there any good known solutions/libraries for how to do this?

```
class User(models.Model):
avatar = models.ImageField(
    default='images/avatars/profile.png',
    upload_to=user_directory_path)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="Employee")
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
present = models.BooleanField(default=False)
code = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date_clocked = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
total_holiday = models.DecimalField(
    default=28.0, decimal_places=1, max_digits=4)
holiday_remaining = models.DecimalField(
    default=28.0, decimal_places=1, max_digits=4)
```

My model is shown above I need to reset the remaining_holiday field on a admin user defined day each year.

Comment: If your use case is as simple as once a year - just go for a cronjob + Django management command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup crontab in your host, or use an equivalent django plugin like this one: https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab